# How to know the owner who shared this file in this context in Django?

Tags: django

I have a table like this:

```
+----+----------+----------+----------------+----------------------------------+
| id | users_id | files_id | shared_user_id | shared_date                      |
+----+----------+----------+----------------+----------------------------------+
|  3 |        1 |        1 |              2 | 2013-01-31 14:27:06.523908+00:00 |
|  2 |        1 |        1 |              2 | 2013-01-31 14:25:37.760192+00:00 |
|  4 |        1 |        3 |              2 | 2013-01-31 14:46:01.089560+00:00 |
|  5 |        1 |        1 |              3 | 2013-01-31 14:50:54.917337+00:00 |
```

Now I want to know the owner of each files who shared the file. For file 1, users_id is 1. I want to get the name of users_id 1 from the default Django auth_user table. I want to get the usernames for each file. How can I do that?

```
#models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class File(models.Model):
    users = models.ForeignKey(User)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.TextField()
    end_date = models.TextField()
    duration = models.TextField()
    size_overview = models.IntegerField()
    size = models.TextField()
    flag = models.TextField()
    #delete_date = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

class Share(models.Model):
    users = models.ForeignKey(User)
    files = models.ForeignKey(File)
    shared_user_id = models.IntegerField()
    shared_date = models.TextField()

class Host(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    full_path = models.TextField()
```

Comment: What's the point of showing this table? Why don't you show the model definitions, they would be far more useful.

Comment: have you wrote any query to get result ? please post that and that help us to help u :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've said to you before, your model structure is a bit odd - in particular, `Share.shared_user` should be a ForeignKey, not an IntegerField. In this case, you could help things by making `users` a ManyToManyField from `File` to `User`, using `Share` as the `through` table:

```
class File(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Share')
```

Now given a `File` instance you can simply do:

```
my_file.users.count()
```

Comment: I want to get the username not the number of users.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. But if so, I really don't understand why you are asking: it's not even a query, you just do `my_share.users.username`. This is really basic stuff that's covered in the tutorial.

Comment: my_share? Where does this come from

Comment: It's a random name I made up for your Share instance. Presumably you're doing it in a for loop: `for my_share in Share.objects.all():`...

Comment: That's it! Thanks once again.